# spring boot dependency not found

Tags: spring-boot

I have spring boot application with documentum dependency (dfc.jar). The application works fine in debug mode (by specifying jvmArguments in spring-boot-maven-plugin and attaching a debugger through IDE). But the bundled application throws error when I put it on a different box. Please help.

Comment: Could you paste the contents of your `pom.xml` and also what the actual error is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on your error

As m4ktub said you need your dfc's (and depending) libraries in the classpath of the JVM running your application. In case of web application you  would probably bundle this in your webapp's lib folder.

Also you might not referencing your dfc.properties - it should also be in your VM's classpath.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed *DFC* then the installer changed the `Classpath` environment variable. This may be the reason why it works on your first box and not the second.

If that is the case, then you need to define the `Classpath` in all the places where your run it.